# Change node type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Using jQuery, is it possible to change all matched elements to a different type?

For example, can I select all `a` tags, `$("a")`, and change them to `input`s?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but my guess would be no.  Unless you mean change them by removing them from the DOM and adding some new elements in their place, which should be possible.

Comment: @Brad - Maybe to create inline editable hyperlinks?

Comment: @aroth, ah, that would make sense.

Comment: @Brad - and for userscripts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't actually change it, but you can replace them with a new element using the [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method:

```
$("a").replaceWith("<input>");
```

If there are any attributes that you want to keep, you'll need to manually set them:

```
$("a").replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<input>", {
        class: this.className,
        value: this.innerHTML
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be fine, but he is going to have to copy over the attributes himself.  Not that that is a bad thing...

Comment: Will this retain the inner HTML content of the tags being replaced?

Comment: @esqew: No, but an `<input>` doesn't have inner content. Did you want to set the `value` of the input? I'll update.

Answer (score 16):

Changing an A element to an INPUT element isn't changing the type, it is changing the *tagName*. According to the [DOM 2 Core specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815), an element's *tagName* is readonly, so no, you can't set it.

However, you can replace an element with a different element, provided it is valid in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard JavaScript's [ChildNode.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) method can do this. Run example.

```js
var element = document.querySelector("span");
var elementInnerHTML = element.innerHTML;
var newElement = document.createElement("h1");
newElement.innerHTML = elementInnerHTML;

element.replaceWith(newElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>hightekk.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span>
    Hello World
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("a").each( function() {
    this.replaceWith( $("<input>").html( this.innerHTML() ) );
});
```

Comment: Seems like you're kinda guessing at things. Just a few hints, `this.replaceWith(...` should be `$(this).replaceWith(...`, `$("<input>").html(...` should be `$("<input>").val(...`, `this.innerHTML()` should be `this.innerHTML`.

Comment: An input element has no content, so setting its innerHTML may have no effect, or may throw an error.