# How to convert an input submit element to a button element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert an `<input type="submit">` button to a `<button>` element along with all it's id, class, events, tabindex etc.

Any idea on a good approach?
jQuery is also an option.

**Note:** I do not have access to the original `<input type="submit">` html code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change node type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728409/change-node-type)

Comment: @hitautodestruct If you do not have access to the original html you need to do everything manually or your explanation is a little bit unclear

Comment: Why? For preventing form submission? If yes, there are better ways for doing this.

Comment: @Bernhard The original html is generated using an external source. But I can manipulate the source using javascript.

Comment: @undefined I need to have a `button` element since I am using an icon font for the text and the value attribute can't take any entities.

Comment: @mechanicalfish That question doesn't answer how I can copy over the event and other attributes.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = document.yourWayOfSelectingIt('maybeAnID');

input.outerHTML = input.outerHTML.replace(/^\<input/, '<button') + input.value + '</button>';
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GgGtq/1/)

Comment: what about the rest of the attrbutes? id, tabindex, class, events?

Comment: It replaces `<input` by `<submit` using regexp, then adds value to the inside and a closing tag. It doesn't do anything with attributes, so they are all conserved. As for events, you should attach them after the replacement, if that can't be done then there is no solution for your problem that I know of - you would have to do that by manually attaching them back one by one.

Comment: In jQuery, you can get events using `.data('events')` but I hear there is a problem with scope. You could also `.clone(true)` to create new element, but that would put you back in square 1 as you would still need to change the tagName.

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity and library independence. works for me.

Comment: ... but does not work in ie11 apparently. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It's a working solution to fetch all attributes and replace the original element with the button element. For the attributes not required on new element a condition can be placed after "this.specified" condition.

```
    <form action="test.php" action="post">
        <input id="submit" type="submit"  />
    </form>


    <script>
        var oSubmitButton = $('input[type="submit"]');
        var oForm = oSubmitButton.closest('form');
        var sOriginAttrs = '';

        $.each(oSubmitButton[0].attributes, function() {
            if (this.specified) {
                sOriginAttrs += ' ' + this.name + '="' + this.value + '"';
            }
        });

        oSubmitButton.replaceWith($('<button ' + sOriginAttrs + '>').text('Submit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            //Maybe a form submit
            //oForm.submit();
        }));
    </script>
```

Created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wD9V/)