# Alter unappened element's html tag type with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have an element created by another process, created in a method akin to

```
var their_element = document.createElement("div");
/* Lots of stuff is done to their_element */
```

And that object is being passed to me later. It has not been appended anywhere yet. The problem is, I need it to be different html tag type when it finally hits the html, such as:

```
<form></form>
```

How do i change it? The solutions I have found involve editing after it's appended, not before.

Edit: 
Also, learned nodeName can't be assigned for this.

```
their_element.nodeName = "FORM"
```

doesn't work.

Also, this doesn't work either:

```
their_element.tagName = "FORM"
```

Also this didn't work either:

```
var outside = their_element.outerHTML;
outside = outside.replace(/div/g, 'form');
their_element.outerHTML = outside;
```

All of these still leave it as a DIV when appended.
(And I'm not looking for jQuery)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, it seems like you may be adding complexity to a problem?

Comment: That doesn’t really make sense… if you need a `<form>`, use `document.createElement("form")`. Maybe, pass the node name to a function and use `document.createElement(nodeName)`.

Comment: The point is, there's been work done to the element already, styling, adding contents, assigning an id, etc. And the script that adds it is pretty much outside of scope to edit.

Comment: Just to clarify, why do you need to transform this `<div>` into a  `<form>`? Could you append the div into a form instead?

Comment: The div is the default of the function passing the element along. The function I'm currently making is attempting to expand what it can do to make it so it can can be used to make forms, spans, etc. as well. Form's really just an example. It's about expanding the functionality of some other code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [DOM 2 core specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815) declares `tagName` as `readonly`. (I was drawn to this fact from a similar (not dupe) [question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728409/change-node-type) in a jQuery context.)

Comment: That's annoying. Means finding a solution will be harder as it will have to find a workaround or loophole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on this for cross-browser compatability, but there are properties and methods on elements that could be of use. Particularly, `Element.attributes`, `Element.hasAttributes()`, and `Element.setAttribute()`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

I'm not going to use ES6 here, so we don't have to worry about transpiling. You can update if you want:

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id="random";
    el.style.background="red";
    el.style.width="200px";
    el.style.padding="10px";
    el.style.margin="10px";
    el.innerHTML="<input type='submit' value='submit'>";

console.log({"Element 1": el});

var newEl = document.createElement('form');

console.log({"Element 2 Before Transformation": newEl})

if (el.hasAttributes()) {
    var attr = el.attributes
    for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
        var name = attr[i].name, val = attr[i].value;
        newEl.setAttribute(name, val)
    }
}

if (el.innerHTML) { newEl.innerHTML = el.innerHTML }

console.log({"Element 2 After Transformation": newEl})

document.body.append(el);
document.body.append(newEl);
```

There are certain properties you need to account for like `innerHTML`, `innerText`, and `textContent` that would overwrite one another if multiples are set. You may also have to account for `childNodes` and what not.

Comment: Although it might not fit every use case, using your solution and ending it with a `el = newEl;` does it for mine. Awesome!