# Way to replace all divs (ignore their class and IDs) - extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need a simple extension that deletes all divs (with any ID or class).
Extension should be running in WP text editor, so I'm using

textEditor.value = textEditor.value

I guess it should use .replaceAll, but I'm not sure how to word expression to delete all divs and ignore their ID and class. Both ID and class should be deleted also.

Example:

```
<div id="example1" class="example2">Text</div>
```

Should be just:

```
<p>Text<p>
```

Comment: You can try using the `getElementsByTagName` and pass "div" as argument. It will return all the divs then loop and change them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var html = elem.innerHTML;
var parent = elem.parentNode;
var textEl = document.createElement('p')
textEl.innerHTML = html
parent.appendChild(textEl)
```

Comment: This post might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728409/change-node-type

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what's div ID nor class name. I just need to remove them all. This doesn't really help as it have specific class.

Answer (score 0):

This will search for all **div** tags in the current DOM. And replace it with the **span** tag.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var l = divs.length
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
  var text = divs[i].innerText;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = text;
  divs[i].replaceWith(p);
}
```